# Cómo resolver este error en la eliminación de elementos repetidos en una lista?

Tags: python, lista

He estado probando este código en PYTHON para eliminar elementos repetidos en una lista, y me funciona con todos los números excepto con el 4 que se repite dos veces:

```
lista = [1, 2, 10, 4, 11, 4, 1, 4, 2, 6, 8, 2, 9, 9, 10, 10, 8, 11]

lista.sort()#l=[1,1,2,2,2,4,4,4,6,9]

for i in lista:#4
    veces=lista.count(i)#3
    if veces>1:#True
        lista.remove(i)

print("La lista solo con elementos únicos:")
print(lista)
```

Comment: python ? php ? js ?

Comment: probá con: for i in lista.copy(): así recorres una copia de la lista para que no se modifiquen los índices.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Sin mayúsculas sostenidas, por favor.

Comment: Alfabravo editó tu pregunta quitándole las mayúsculas sostenidas debido a estas dan la impresión de que estás gritando. Te recomiendo tenerlo en cuenta la próxima vez que hagas una pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con comprensión de listas:

```
nueva = [lista[i] for i in range(len(lista)) if lista[i] not in lista[:i]]
```

Generamos una nueva lista recorriendo la lista original, seleccionando aquellos elementos que no estén entre los elementos previos.

**Demo**

```
lista = [1, 2, 10, 4, 11, 4, 1, 4, 2, 6, 8, 2, 9, 9, 10, 10, 8, 11]
nueva = [lista[i] for i in range(len(lista)) if lista[i] not in lista[:i]]
print(nueva)
```

produce

```
[1, 2, 10, 4, 11, 6, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 3):

Solución 1. Recorrer la lista y copiar los valores sólo una vez:

```
resultado = []
for elem in lista:
    if elem not in resultado:
        resultado.append(elem)
```

Solución 2. Usar set():

```
resultado = list(set(lista))
```

Comment: Es importante aclarar que usando `set` el orden de los elementos en la lista resultante puede no ser el mismo que la lista original.